# Spock & Spock Reports how retrieve the MockHttpServletResponse (from Spring MVC Testing) for the where block?

Tags: spock, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spock-reports

I am working with

- Gradle
- Spring MVC Testing
- Spock Core
- Spock Spring
- Spock Reports

In some *Specification* I have the following:

I was able to do the following:

```
def ResultActions resultActions // instance variables
def MockHttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse // instance variables

…
@Unroll(value="#methodNameReport Expected")    
def "something"(){

….
when: "GET"

    resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(url, PersonaControllerHelper.ID)).andDo(print())
    mockHttpServletResponse = resultActions.andReturn().getResponse()
    println mockHttpServletResponse
    println mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus()
}
```

Until here, I am able to get in peace the `MockHttpServletResponse` class and print some data. Therefore `MockHttpServletResponse` **is not** *null*.

But later:

```
where: "."

    urlReport << [PersonaXmlFindOneWithProducesControllerTemplateFactory.findOneRequestParamById(PersonaControllerHelper.ID)]
    classNameReport << [PersonaXmlFindOneWithProducesController.class.getSimpleName()]
    methodNameReport << ["findOneRequestParamById"]
    statusReport << [mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus()]
    mediaTypeReport << [MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE]
```

I get

```
PersonaXmlFindOneWithProducesControllerTest.groovy: 90: 
Only @Shared and static fields may be accessed from here @ line 90, column 21.
            statusReport << [mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus()]
```

Even If I declare the variable *static* or with *@Shared*

I get

```
…..PersonaXmlFindOneWithProducesControllerTest > findOneRequestParamById Expected FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at PersonaXmlFindOneWithProducesControllerTest.groovy:90
```

The wonderful NullPointerException.

What configuration settings is need it?

**Alpha**

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

def String url

def String urlReport
def String methodNameReport
def String statusReport

def ResultActions resultActions 
def @Shared MockHttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse

def setup(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Unroll(value="#methodNameReport Expected")
def "findOneRequestParamById Expected"(){

    given: "URL: #urlReport"

        url = PersonaXmlFindOneControllerURLURIFactory.findOneRequestParamById()

    when: "GET"

        resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(url, PersonaControllerHelper.ID)).andDo(print())
        mockHttpServletResponse = resultActions.andReturn().getResponse()
        println mockHttpServletResponse //prints
        println mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus() //prints

    then: "Exists - Status: #statusReport"

        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk())

    where: "."

        urlReport << [PersonaXmlFindOneControllerTemplateFactory.findOneRequestParamById(PersonaControllerHelper.ID)]
        methodNameReport << ["findOneRequestParamById"]
        statusReport << [mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus()] // Fails
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole specification? Here or on github/pastebin..

Comment: Hi @Opal done. Check Alpha section. Thanks

Comment: Unless I am missing something your test is completely wrong. All the variables (urlReport, methodNameReport and statusReport) are defined in the where block but never actually used in the code. Also since you just use one iteration you do not actually need the where block. Just use the value directly

Comment: I suggest you re-read the Spock documentation for parameterized tests.

Comment: (1) Variables declared on `where` block are used, in the snippet code all of them are not included to avoid do verbose the question (2) a variable declared on `where` block is used in `@Unroll` (for example `methodNameReport`) and the others are used in block's text value, for example `statusReport` on `then` block. (3) Any value located on the right of `<<` **must be** static.